# <main> noise in assistive technology

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, jaws-screen-reader, accessibility

I'm improving accessibilty of my app with ARIA tags. In the project i'm using Angular 1.6.5, html, css, js and node.js.

One funny thing is when the Assistive Technology, Jaws in this case, reach the native tag `<main>` they read all variables linked with angular on $scope. 
Making the flow read noising once they didn't stop talk until get the last variable.

I already fixed the problem, but I'm curious why this happens, any idea?

Comment: It would seem that the screen reader reads the code prior to Angular transforming it. How did you fix the problem?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Just changing <main> for <div>

Comment: Ah. That may make some sense. The last time I checked JAWS doesn't recognize the HTML5 sectioning elements (`main`, `article`, `nav`, `aside`, `section`) for constructing a document outline to work from. **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML_sections_and_outlines)** and the W3C actually advise not to use these elements for assistive technology purposes.

Comment: totally @ScottMarcus, thanks.